# how to make a OS hard drive extended with another hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-utility

I have 30GB for my Windows Seven installation and an extra 320GB hard drive. I would like to extend them together so that I don't have to specify each and every installation of an application. I have used the disk utility and partition master but they do not have the option or do not allow me too. Is there a tweak or a program that will allow me to do this?

Comment: What version of windows 7? This is not trivial in any circumstances, but if you don't have at least win 7 pro (I think) it's not possible at all.  IIRC, Home Premium doesn't support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with Windows, you'll need to upgrade to Win7 Professional, and create a spanned volume.

Answer (score 1):

If your motherboard supports RAID 0 you should be able to configure a volume that contains two drives.  However, they generally have to be the same size.  Also note that this configuration more than DOUBLES your chance of a catastrophic failure.  Make sure you have good and frequent backups.